# Timeout Error while sending an email using my mail client software

Tags: python, email, smtp

im getting a AttributeError when i want to send a message using this mail client software that im working on. can anyone tell how to fix this error. here is the functions for the send email:

```
def compose_email(self):
    # Create a dialog to compose a new email
    dialog = QDialog(self)
    dialog.setWindowTitle('Compose Email')
    # Set up the form layout
    form = QFormLayout()
    # Add fields for the recipient, subject, and message body
    self.recipient_field = QLineEdit(dialog)
    form.addRow('To:', self.recipient_field)
    self.subject_field = QLineEdit(dialog)
    form.addRow('Subject:', self.subject_field)
    self.message_field = QTextEdit(dialog)
    form.addRow('Message:', self.message_field)
    # Add a "Add Attachment" button
    self.add_attachment_button = QPushButton('Add Attachment', dialog)
    self.add_attachment_button.clicked.connect(self.add_attachment)
    form.addRow(self.add_attachment_button)
    # Add a "Send" button and a "Cancel" button
    buttons = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, dialog)
    buttons.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
    buttons.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)
    form.addRow(buttons)
    # Set the layout of the dialog
    dialog.setLayout(form)
    # Show the dialog and get the result
    result = dialog.exec_()

        # If the user clicked the "Send" button, send the email
    try:
     if result == QDialog.Accepted:
        recipient = self.recipient_field.text()
        subject = self.subject_field.text()
        message = self.message_field.toPlainText()
        attachments = self.attachments
        self.send_email(recipient, subject, message, attachments)
    except Exception as e:
     print("if user clicked An error occurred while sending the message:", e)

def add_attachment(self):
    # Open a file dialog to select an attachment
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.ReadOnly
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select Attachment', '',
                                               'All Files (*);;Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.bmp);;Videos (*.mp4 *.avi *.mov)',
                                               options=options)
    try:
     if file_name:
        # Add the selected file to the attachments list
        self.attachments.append(file_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("attach An error occurred while sending the message:", e)
def send_email(self, recipient, subject, message, attachments):
    # Connect to the SMTP server
    try:
        smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmx.com',587)
        smtp_server.login(self.mailbox.username, self.mailbox.password)
    except Exception as e:
        # Display an error message if the login failed
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', 'Failed to connect to the SMTP server'+ e)
        return

    # Create the email message
    msg = email.message.EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = self.mailbox.user
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.set_content(message)
    # Add the attachments to the message
    for file_name in attachments:
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_name)
            msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)

    # Send the email
    try:
        smtp_server.send_message(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        # Display an error message if the send failed
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', f'Failed to send the email: {e}')
        return

    # Close the connection to the SMTP server
    smtp_server.quit()

    # Display a success message///////
    QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success', 'The email was sent successfully')
```

I Will be thankful if anyone can be help to fix it
i tried to debug the code by adding print statements the and its printing the subject and recepient, i guess its with the attachment, but i dont how to fix it and im not its because of it. i tried sending with and without attachments and im still getting this error. the authentication with SMTP server is working fine.
here is the error message i am getting: An error occurred while sending the message: can only concatenate str (not "AttributeError") to str

Comment: add the full error traceback.

Comment: You error message states **message: can only concatenate str (...** So look for any concatenation in your code, although the traceback should provide the actual line number that is failing